# read data from text file and display in cols and rows

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I'm new to this forum.  I need help.  I have a text file with Node Names and software names in one long column of a text file.

I'd like to know how to read in each Node Name and its software name.  Each node name will be a col header, under each node name it will be the software names....the code will loop thru and read all the software name until it reaches the next node name and starts a new col header and repeat again until EOF.

Any idea on how to do that?

My text file has something like this:

Node Name: ServerName #1
software name: abc
software name: def
software name: ghi
software name: etc...
on...
and on...
and on...
Node Name: ServerName #2
software name: xyz
and on...
and and on...
plus more...
etc...
next Node Name: ServerName #3
etc...

Expected Output:

Node Name: ServerName #1-------Node Name: ServerName #2------Node Name: ServerName #3
software name: abc-------------------software name: xyz-------------------etc...
software name: def-------------------and on...
software name: ghi-------------------and and on...
software name: etc.------------------plus more...
on...--------------------------------------etc...
and on...
and on...

Hope this sample data helps to clarify my explanation above.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: "in one long column of a text file." - please show us what that looks like - copy-paste the first 5-10 lines (including header, if any) [into your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67181434/edit) if possible

Answer (score 0):

For VBA:

To get text from a text file you can use [Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/open-statement). If your text file has each entry on a new line, you can read from the text file directly into an array, line by line.

Once you have your array, you can search for the headers and pass the values over from this one dimension array into a two dimension array.

Since I don't know what your file looks like, this is just a suggestion of how it might be done.

Example of how to use Open:

```vb
Function ReadFrom(ByVal FilePath As String) As String
    Dim TextFile As Integer, TextBody As String, Data As String
    TextFile = FreeFile 'VBA uses a number as a reference for files, FreeFile returns the next available number
    Open FilePath For Input Access Read As TextFile
    
    Do Until EOF(TextFile)
        Line Input #TextFile, Data
        TextBody = TextBody & Data
    Loop

    Close #TextFile
    
    ReadFrom = TextBody
End Function
```

Example with the text array included:

```vb
Function ReadFrom(ByVal FilePath As String, ByVal AsArray As Boolean) As Variant
    Dim TextFile As Integer, TextBody As String, Data As String, TextArray() As String, LineCount As Long
    ReDim TextArray(1 To 100000) As String
    
    TextFile = FreeFile 'VBA uses a number as a reference for files, FreeFile returns the next available number
    Open FilePath For Input Access Read As TextFile
    
    Do Until EOF(TextFile)
        Line Input #TextFile, Data
        If AsArray Then
            LineCount = LineCount + 1
            TextArray(LineCount) = Data
        Else
            TextBody = TextBody & Data
        End If
    Loop

    Close #TextFile
    
    If AsArray Then
        Redim Preserve TextArray(1 to LineCount)
        ReadFrom = TextArray
    Else
        ReadFrom = TextBody
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: So which is that VBA, VBScript or PowerShell as the OP tagged all three so how do you know how to answer?

Comment: My answer is in VBA. I will edit my answer to say that.

Comment: I realised that, the point I was trying to make is multiple language tag questions aren’t an invitation to leave an answer that fits one of the tags. In fact, it’s usually a clear indicator a question is "Too Broad" and should be flagged as such.

Comment: If this was a "forum" I would agree, but it isn’t and there are plenty of existing questions and answers covering this topic. The mistake many make is thinking SO is a traditional forum but it’s not.